# Why won't QGroupBox widgets dynamically resize with rest of window?

Tags: qt, resize, pyqt, qwidget, qgroupbox

I have a QMainWindow with the widgets laid out in a grid. They all resize proportionally when the window resizes as expected, except for the widgets placed inside a QGroupBox. The QGroupBox itself resizes, but the widgets inside just stay on the same place. If I apply a lay out on the QGroupBox, the widgets loose their original positions. Note that I'm using the .ui file with PyQt4. You can get the file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B70NMOBg3HZtQkJtNng5cV9IUGM).

And this is what happens:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The widgets inside the group box must be in a layout. If they are not in a layout, their size is fixed (the layout manages the size, no layout, no resize)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the widgets lose their original positions"? (PS: please do not link to code on other sites - put it in the question itself).

Comment: I mean that if I apply a layout on the QGroupBox all widgets inside accommodate themselves according the layout type. Even if it's a Grid layout, they don't stay where you see them in the screenshot, but occupy positions completely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Qt documentation on QGroupBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgroupbox.html):

> QGroupBox doesn't automatically lay out the child widgets (which are
>   often QCheckBoxes or QRadioButtons but can be any widgets).

There is an example showing how to setup a layout for a `QGroupBox` (which is the same a setting up a layout for any `QWidget` based object meant to store other objects, like `QFrame` for instance).

You must create a layout, call `QGroupBox::setLayout` and then add widgets to the layout. If you use QtCreator, right-click the `QGroupBox` and select the layout you want to use for it from the context menu.

Comment: Thank you.
I ended up just getting rid of the QGroupBox and playing with layouts until got it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem programmatically, by overriding the QWidget's resizeEvent:

```
void CustomInput::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) { 
    // Call the original resize from base class
    QWidget::resizeEvent(e);

    // Only attempt to resize if box exists and the driving event is not app start
    if (groupBox != NULL && e->oldSize().width() > 0) {
        // Update
        groupBox->resize(e->size().width(), groupBox->height());
    }
}
```